# get in single MySql query from this four

Tags: php, mysql

want to combine this **4 query** **in single** mysql  query and my current query is

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM projectFiles pf  
        INNER JOIN projectFileFolders pff ON pf.folderID = pff.folderID 
        WHERE pff.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' AND folderType=3"

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM projectFiles pf 
        INNER JOIN projectProducts pp ON pf.fileID = pp.fileID 
        WHERE pp.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."'"

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM projectFiles pf  
        INNER JOIN projectMaintenance pm ON pf.fileID = pm.fileID 
        WHERE pm.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' "

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM projectFiles pf  
        INNER JOIN projectServices ps ON pf.fileID = ps.fileID 
        WHERE ps.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' "
```

Comment: Add the ddl's and format the queries as code please.

Comment: Some test data and expected output would be great.

Comment: Maybe list the names of the expected result fields please?

Comment: Add some context: why do you want to combine them?  Depending on your table structure and other conditions, it may be much faster to run 4 independent simple queries instead of 1 long and complex one.

Comment: expected result field is fieldId and fileDescription

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you have four tables, and you want to include any records from those tables whose projectID matches the one in your provided `$row['projectID']` field.  If so, you can simply combine all your queries like this:

```
$sqlWhatever = 
    "SELECT * FROM projectFiles pf  
     INNER JOIN projectFileFolders pff ON pf.folderID = pff.folderID 
     INNER JOIN projectProducts pp ON pf.fileID = pp.fileID 
     INNER JOIN projectMaintenance pm ON pf.fileID = pm.fileID 
     INNER JOIN projectServices ps ON pf.fileID = ps.fileID 
     WHERE pff.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' AND folderType=3
        OR pp.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' 
        OR pm.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' 
        OR ps.projectID =  '".$row['projectID']."' "
```

Now, you haven't said whether each of the four tables has the same fileID's or not.  If they do not, then change your INNER join to a LEFT join, or you'll only get records that have a common fileID in each of the four tables.

Comment: Data requires from all that table and fileId from each table is different.And from projectFiles I need is fileID and fileDescription from projectFiles and after that data need to get identified that this file is related to particular table.(Is that possible?)

Comment: Probably possible.  Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN and you'll get all the records.  On the other hand, a better way to do this is to run your four different queries in a stored procedure, inserting the results into a single temporary table as you go.  Then you can select everything from the temporary table and you'll have your desired result.  As one of the comments says, your solution is very vulnerable to hacking.